# vaadin 14.2.2 Grid not creating an output

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I am playing around with vaadin 14.2.2 for testing purpose. However, I got to the first problem using Grid immediately. The Example from https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 1543),
        new Person("Galileo Galilei", 1564),
        new Person("Johannes Kepler", 1571));

// Create a grid bound to the list
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(people);
grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setHeader("Name");
grid.addColumn(Person::getYearOfBirth)
        .setHeader("Year of birth");

layout.add(grid);
```

does not generate an output in the visualization. Also the hint in several GitHub issues to use

> grid.setSizeFull();

does not solve this issue.
Has anybody any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Check in your browser via the DOM inspector.  Find the grid in the page.  If there are empty/nearly empty tags like .e.g `vaadin-grid` or alike, most likely you have not properly setup your dev-env as client side deps can not be loaded and run.  If the grid seems to be populated make sure it has "room to show" (e.g. it might have just beed collapsed)

Comment: Thank you @cfrick, however, this is not my first web project. And the hint you provided is already checked. There is a vaadin-grid and some internel elements. But no data which could be shown. In the meanwhile I updated to vaadin 16 and here it works.

Comment: If you vaadin-grid tag seems relatively empty go compare it with e.g. the live demo of the grid to be sure.  But i am relatively certain, that your build lacks some "prepare-frontent"-like task to be run here.  Or you have defined the deps wrong.

Comment: Have you created the initial stub from the [vaadin/start](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page or did you just include Vaadin dependencies in an already existing project? Do you have any errors or 404 in the console log of the browser? I agree with the @cfrick, it seems to be a configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works for me on Vaadin 14.2.2 + Spring:

```
@Route("MainView")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
                new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 1543),
                new Person("Galileo Galilei", 1564),
                new Person("Johannes Kepler", 1571));

        // Create a grid bound to the list
        Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setItems(people);
        grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setHeader("Name");
        grid.addColumn(Person::getYearOfBirth).setHeader("Year of birth");

        add(grid);
    }

    class Person {
        String name;
        Integer yearofbirth;

        public Person(String name, Integer yearofbirth) {
            this.name = name;
            this.yearofbirth = yearofbirth;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getYearOfBirth() {
            return yearofbirth;
        }

        public void setYearOfBirth(Integer yearofbirth) {
            this.yearofbirth = yearofbirth;
        }
    }
}
```